# How can I permanently set xrandr monitor position?

Tags: x11, xrandr

I have two monitors on my setup (Arch Linux). I have my main screen in front of me and a secondary screen to the left. On startup, X session assumes that monitor 2 is on the right. I can change this with:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-A-2 --left-of DisplayPort-0
```

However, running this at startup everyday isn't ideal. I tried editing `.xinitrc` with:

```
exec xrandr --output HDMI-A-2 --left-of DisplayPort-0
```

But this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in `.Xsession`, works for me.

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output DP-4 --auto
xrandr --output DP-6 --auto
xrandr --output DP-4 --left-of DP-6
```

Why do you use `exec` here? Try without `exec`.